# Can I make a link to specific place in HTML document using Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have existing html tag which links to another page :

```
<a href="information.html#yardInf">yard</a>

So this will navigate me to specific place in information.html
My question is how can i do the same using Thymeleaf ?
```

Comment: Thymeleaf generates html... that link works no differently in Thymeleaf than a regular html page.  Have you tried this, and is there a problem with it?

Comment: I've changed @RequestMapping(value ="/information" ) to value="/information. html) and it works as I wanted. I had no explicit mapping error before this change. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: You can use `<a href="information#yardInf">yard</a>` (removed the `.html`) just as easily.  There's no requirement about having a file extension in the url.

Comment: Yes, actually changing RequestMapping to /information.html made all links with extension .html work but broke the thymeleaf links i had because they map to "/information" (without .html). So after i brought back the RequestMapping to /information and remove all .html extensions of the rest of the links everything works proper now. Thanks for the clarifications.